# Rename file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have a file `1353683037.jpg` in the tmp folder as shown below:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_project\public\images\tmp\1353683037.jpg
```

I need to rename this file to:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_project\public\images\main\1353683037.jpg
```

To do this, I have done the following:

```
$file = '1353683037.jpg';
$dir = './public/images/';
rename($dir.'tmp\'. $file, $dir.'main\'. $file);
```

I'm having the follwing reply from the server:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: rename(./public/images/tmp/1353683037.jpg,../public/images/main/1353683037.jpg) [function.rename]: The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

Filename: controllers/test.php

Line Number: 1
```

What could possibly be the problem? Thanks

Comment: it shows you that the path is wrong, try an absolute path to check if it works, then if doesn't works check chmod of the folders

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gives me the absolute path which still does not work. The path works in the windows explorer though

Comment: no i mean write down by hands the path and see if is there an error

Comment: Weird! the copy function seems to works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible reasons that your code will not work:

**First** - You are using backslashes for your directory path.  The backslash is escaping some of your characters including the single quote after `tmp` and `main`.  Even though your windows environment uses backslashes, you should use forward.

---

**Second** - Your path is likely incorrect. Rather than use a relative path, try using an absolute path.

The constant (as set in index.php) `FCPATH` will give you the server path to your base CodeIgniter directory.

So, we should be able to modify your code to the following:

```
$file = $file = '1353683037.jpg';

$oldDir = FCPATH . 'public/images/tmp/';
$newDir = FCPATH . 'public/images/main/';

rename($oldDir.$file, $newDir.$file);
```

If this code does not work, you probably have FCPATH incorrectly set in your index.php file for CodeIgniter.  If it is incorrect, you should change it to the proper path, i.e. `/xampp/htdocs/ci_project/`

Answer (score 1):

it depends from - are you running this commands from codeigniter instanse or from simple php script. 
in 1st case, usually, folder where ci looking files is public - its site /
 and path to file is  images/tmp/1353683037.jpg

in 2 case path will be correct if 
for example /var/www/public/...  and you script in /var/www/ because  ./ in path means that in current directory where is public dir

Answer (score -1):

use

```
$this->config->item('base_url')
```

instead of FCPATH