# Implementing rename()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im new to this renaming files and Im using codeigniter. But renaming file cant seem to work. I've tried this one without using codeigniter and sure does it renames file. Why is it not working on codeigniter? Is there a way to make it work or my approach is just not right? How does renaming file work on codeigniter?

```
function renameFile(){
            $filename = "test.xlsx";
            $uploads = "./uploads/";
            $path= substr($uploads, 1);
            $root= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project';
            $newname = "test2";
            $getExtension = end(explode('.', $filename));
            $ext = ".".$getExtension;

            rename($root.$path.$filename, $root.$path.$newname.$ext);
}
```

Without using codeigniter, calling its function will make it work.

Comment: Try this example from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532633/rename-file-in-codeigniter

Comment: are you sure you getting right path at your `$root` variable? You can use `FCPATH` to get root path